# Why I always need to start Tor at least two times so it starts correctly?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

...and don't get the red web page that says "something went wrong", this is version 10.0.9 on Windows, this didn't happened before, the startup was smooth. wtf ?

Comment: show the screenshot

Comment: I sometimes get the same problem as well and for me, it's because I click on another application while Tor is starting up.